# MDDropDownItem Dynamic implemetnation

Tags: python, user-interface, drop-down-menu, kivy, material-design

My objective was to have a dropdown item, with relative dropdown menu, and a "+" button below it that would trigger the "+" icon to be replaced by a new dropdown item and have the "+" icon reappear below this, ready to add a third dropdown item and so on.

I ve been on this for a while.
I ve tried a custom widget but i might have gotten the code wrong..
I ve tried a method to build the MDDropDownItem and many more.
The problem is always a KeyError: 'label_item'.
As it seems, a MDDropDownItem doesn t get inizialized with this property if it s created in the python file... this seems weird to me, so here I am!

Next i m posting the simplest way of getting the error. If someone can solve this would be amazing!

Python file:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.dropdownitem import MDDropDownItem
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
import sqlite3
import os

class ExampleApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        
        return Builder.load_file('example.kv')
    

    def set_dropmenutext(self, text):
        self.root.ids.types_dropdownmenu.text = text
        self.menu.dismiss()

    def open_menu(self, call):

        menu_items = [{"text": i, 
                       "viewclass": "OneLineListItem", 
                       "on_release": lambda x= i: self.set_dropmenutext(x)} for i in ["INTEGER", "REAL", "TEXT", "BLOB", "NULL"]]
        
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
                        caller=call,
                        items=menu_items,
                        width_mult=4,
                        position="auto")
        
        self.menu.open()
        
    def add_column(self):
        
        grid = self.root.ids.column_grid
        add_btn = self.root.ids.add_col

        grid.remove_widget(add_btn)

        ddi = MDDropDownItem(text= "Select Type")

        grid.add_widget(ddi)


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    ExampleApp().run()
```

KV file:

````
MDBoxLayout:
    MDGridLayout:
        id: column_grid
        cols: 1

        RelativeLayout:

            MDDropDownItem:
                id: types_dropdownmenu
                text: "Select Type"
                font_size: 18
                size_hint: (0.3, 0.5)
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.2, 'center_y': 1}
                on_release: app.open_menu(self)

        MDIconButton:
            id: add_col
            icon: 'plus-thick'
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text_color: (0.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
            user_font_size: "20sp"
            on_release: app.add_column()
    ```


Sorry for the formatting i guess. I never undertood how to make it work properly...
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the `text` of a `MDDropDownItem` before the `ids` have been established. Setting that `text` triggers code in the `MDDropDownItem` to set the `text` of a `Label` in the `MDDropDownItem`. That code uses the `id` of the `Label` (`label_item`) to do it.

You can avoid the error by delaying the setting of that `text` until the `ids` are set up. One way to do that is by using `Clock.schedule_once()`:

```
def add_column(self):
    grid = self.root.ids.column_grid
    add_btn = self.root.ids.add_col

    grid.remove_widget(add_btn)

    ddi = MDDropDownItem()  # do not set text here

    grid.add_widget(ddi)
    
    Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.setup_ddi, ddi))

def setup_ddi(self, ddi, _dt):
    # set the text here
    ddi.text = "Select Type"
```

Comment: Very greatfull.   You actually don t even need all that. Just iniziate the item then add it to the layout and then add the properties! So easy... thanks